# Is there any hack to control the in pdf search of ng2-pdfjs-viewer using angular component

Tags: angular, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I have created a pdfviewer component using ng2-pdfjs-viewer. I want to search for words in pdf using the angular component class.
Metadata from pdf will be displayed in a form, user will click on metadata field and will see first occurrence of that word highlighted in pdf.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have some code to share in order to help you?

Comment: tryied to implement this https://pdfviewer.net/find

Comment: but it is not working in IE11